# -= Operator works but not +=

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm taking the query results, looping over them and trying to make some adjustments before outputting them to the page. I can't seem to get the `+=` operator to work properly across all browsers. Although, the `-=` operator seems to work fine. Basically, `+=` is only concatenating.

I've tried forcing the result to be numeric, but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
var str = '<h2>The Score</h2>'

    for (var i = 0; i < data.message.DATA.length; i++) {

    var theName = data.message.DATA[i][columnMap.ENTRYID]
        switch (theName)
        {
        case "jrd":
            newname = "Carmen";
            theNumber = data.message.DATA[i][columnMap.TOTALCOUNT] -= 110;
            if ($('#entryid').val() == "jrd"){
                $('#recordcount').text(theNumber);
            }
            break;
        case "ejf":
            newname = "Elijah";
            theNumber = Number(data.message.DATA[i][columnMap.TOTALCOUNT] += 50);
            if ($('#entryid').val() == "ejf"){
                $('#recordcount').text(theNumber);
            }
            break;
        }


        str += '<b>'+newname+'</b>'
        str += ' '+theNumber+'<br/>'
    }

    $("#score").html(str)
    }
```

Here's the data returned from my ColdFusion query. I'm using `$.ajax()` to do the call to a CFC...
`{"message":{"COLUMNS":["ENTRYID","TOTALCOUNT"],"DATA":[["ejf","62"],["gdd","52"],["jrd","215"],["kpf","70"]]},"error":false}`

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `+=` call in `Number`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you mean to both increment/decrement `data.message.DATA[i][columnMap.TOTALCOUNT]` while also assigning the new value to `theNumber`?

Comment: It isn't the _result_ you need to be numeric, it is each operand. So you may need to cast data.message.DATA[i] as a number

Comment: Why is `data.message.DATA[i][columnMap.TOTALCOUNT]` a string???

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure why it's being cast as a string. I suspect it's coming bas in my JSON result as a string. I've edited my question to include the result from a call to my ColdFusion query vial `$.ajax()`

Comment: Yes, you then probably should parse the result JSON to numbers, before operating on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to write

```
Number(data.message.DATA[i][columnMap.TOTALCOUNT]) + 50;
```

You're still concatenating *inside* the number call.

Comment: `Number(0) += 1` - `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers fix the half the problem, but you seem to also want the `TOTALCOUNT` set. You could do this long hand but I think you're going for a minimal solution so how about referencing the *Object* as a var, then working with that you can use `+` and `-`, keeping one-liners.

```
/* for (;;) { */

var DATAi = data.message.DATA[i], // added new var `DATAi`
    theName = DATAi[columnMap.ENTRYID];
switch (theName) {
    case "jrd":
        newname = "Carmen";
        theNumber = DATAi[columnMap.TOTALCOUNT] = +DATAi[columnMap.TOTALCOUNT] - 110; // made this match
        if ($('#entryid').val() == "jrd") {
            $('#recordcount').text(theNumber);
        }
        break;
    case "ejf":
        newname = "Elijah";
        theNumber = DATAi[columnMap.TOTALCOUNT] = +DATAi[columnMap.TOTALCOUNT] + 50; // modified
    //  ...
```

Comment: I'm updating two different DOM elements with my script. If you're logged in as jrd, the you would see your "score" in a big box on the right of the page in addition to the list of scores at the bottom of the page. I've shortened the `case` statement quite a bit for this question...

Comment: @Ofeargall Yes well.. I didn't want to say "if `-=` is casting fine, then why not just `-= -50`?" so I wrote an answer that shows casting as well as setting without repeating `data.message.DATA[i]` 4 times. As Objects are ByRef, `o = {a:1}; p = o; p['a'] = 2; o['a'] === 2;`